# getting 403 forbidden when access sharepoint web service from ios in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to ios development and i am trying to access sharepoint web service from ios but i getting `403 forbidden` in response

I have also refer to [this link for authentication](http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2010/07/sharepoint-on-the-iphone-implementation.html) but it doesn't work

Then I try to authenticate using `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` method which i refer from [this link](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1643317)

As per the developer.apple.com documentation this method is deprecated and i use `willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge` method

Following is Code

```
var message:String = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'><soap12:Body><GetList xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>ThemeGallery</listName></GetList></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>"

var urlString = "https://domainname/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"

var url = NSURL(string: urlString)
var req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
var msglength = String(countElements(message))

req.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
req.addValue(msglength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
req.addValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetList", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
req.HTTPMethod = "POST"
req.HTTPBody = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

var connection = NSURLConnection(request: req, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
    connection?.start()
```

#### Connection Methods

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge) {

    if challenge.previousFailureCount == 0
    {
        var newCredential = NSURLCredential(user: self.username, password: self.password, persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)
        challenge.sender.useCredential(newCredential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)

    }
    else
    {
        challenge.sender.cancelAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)

    }
}
```

#### Parsing Methods

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {

    var xmlParser = NSXMLParser(data: self.mutableData)

    xmlParser.delegate = self
    xmlParser.parse()
    xmlParser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = true 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have got solution for authentication to share point web service
>
> I have use `FedAuth` Cookie and `rtFa` Cookie to pass credential
>
> Fisrt I have load the sharepoint login page in `UIWebView`
>
> When user successfully log in. We have to get those `Cookies` by Below method

```
func verifyCookies()
{
    var rtFa:NSHTTPCookie?
    var fedAuth:NSHTTPCookie?
    let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    let cookieArray = storage.cookies!
    
    for tempCookie in cookieArray
    {
        if tempCookie.name == "rtFa"
        {
            rtFa = tempCookie as? NSHTTPCookie
            continue
        }
        else if tempCookie.name == "FedAuth"
        {
            fedAuth = tempCookie as? NSHTTPCookie
            continue
        }
    }
    if rtFa != nil && fedAuth != nil
    {
        self.webView.hidden = true
        self.cookieFound(rtFa!,fedAuthCookie: fedAuth!) // method mention below.
    }  
}
```

> And after that I have use those cookie to pass credential to my request.
>
> Below is my request code

```
func cookieFound(rtFaCookie:NSHTTPCookie,fedAuthCookie:NSHTTPCookie)
{
    var message:String = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>demo</listName><viewName></viewName><query></query><viewFields></viewFields><rowLimit></rowLimit><QueryOptions></QueryOptions><webID></webID></GetListItems></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
    
    var messageLength = String(countElements(message))
    var url = NSURL(string: "https://domain/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx")
    var therequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    
    therequest.addValue(messageLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    therequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    therequest.addValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
    
    // Authentication is passed in request header
    
    var cookieArray = NSArray(objects: rtFaCookie,fedAuthCookie)
    var cookieHeaders = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(cookieArray)
    var requestHeaders = NSDictionary(dictionary: cookieHeaders)
    
    
    therequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = requestHeaders
    therequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    therequest.HTTPBody = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: therequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
    connection?.start()
    
    
}
```

> I have called `verifyCookies()` method from below 'UIWebView delegate' methods

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    self.verifyCookies()
}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    self.verifyCookies()
}
```

> Hope it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it works from a command line invocation of a utility like `curl` i.e. something like

```
curl -D- -u user:password http://....
```

If you see a 403 there, it's likely that Sharepoint doesn't accept HTTP basic authentication, and your code won't work.